# How to generate a PGO optimized native executable with Spring Boot 3?

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm-native-image

I have a Spring Boot 3 Maven application that I compile to a native application on macOS with GraalVM Native Image. Oracle GraalVM Native Image for Java 17 has [profile-guided optimization (PGO)](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/guides/optimize-native-executable-with-pgo/), which improves performance.

How can I use PGO with Spring Boot 3? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76942315/how-to-generate-a-pgo-optimized-native-executable-for-quarkus-app/76954173#76954173) has the answer for doing that with Quarkus.

Comment: Hey @Karsten did you make that work? Have you checked this sample https://github.com/alina-yur/native-spring-boot/tree/main?